# Как сохранять все строки, а не только первую?

Tags: python

Имеется два файла, `file_1` на *±2000 строк*, `file_2` *~100 строк* (стоп слова). Пробую сохранить в файл `result` только строки без стоп слов, но сохраняет только первую строку, помогите разобраться.

```
file_with_keys = open('file_1.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8')
my_keys = open('file_2.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8')
result_file = open('result.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8')

for line in file_with_keys:
    for line_2 in my_keys:
        if any([line_2 not in line for line_2 in my_keys]):
            result_file.write(line)

print('Готово!')
```

Comment: какое-то странное условие у вас. может просто `if line_2 not in line:`?

Comment: Не очень разбираюсь в python, но не надо ли делать перенос строки? По сути, ты перезаписываешь ту же строку.

Answer (score 4):

Если я всё правильно понял, то так:

```
file1 = open('file1.txt', 'r')
file2 = open('file2.txt', 'r')
file_res = open('file_res.txt', 'w')

stopwords = []
for line in file2.readlines():
    stopwords.append(line.strip())

for phrase in file1:
    for i in phrase.split():
        if i in stopwords:
            break
    else:
        file_res.write(phrase)



file1.close()
file2.close()
file_res.close()
```

Остальное, я думаю понятно

Comment: По сути верно, хотя можно написать проще/короче )

Comment: @CrazyElf можно, но ведь он скорее всего новичок

Comment: и поэтому перенос строки надо обрезать не через `strip()`, а таким экзотическим способом? )

Comment: Честно говоря, я сначала так и сделал, но почему-то у меня не сработало. Я пробовал и `strip()`, и `rstrip()`,  и `strip('\n') `, и `line.splitlines()`, но у меня из этого, кроме вот такой экзотики не сработало

Comment: Почемуто у меня этот код не стработал. Просто строки из file1.txt копируются в file_res.txt

Comment: @БорисБондарев попробуйте снова, я поправил код

Comment: @БорисБондарев если помогло, то поставьте галочку пожалуйста, если нет, то отпишитесь

Answer (score 2):

В вашем коде минимум две проблемы:

- Когда вы перебираете строки из файла и он заканчивается, вы не можете перебирать его следующий раз на следующей итерации цикла, потому что файл уже закончился. Надо или открывать второй файл каждый раз заново, или лучше считать из него всё в список и дальше итерироваться по этому списку, а не по файлу.
- У вас лишний второй цикл `for` по `my_keys`, вы ведь и так делаете точно такой же цикл по `my_keys` внутри проверки `if any` (только в виде `list comprehension`), отдельный цикл `for` по `my_keys` просто лишний.